# free() syntax with arguments in C

Tags: c, syntax, malloc, free

I am working on converting many C programs from Unix to Linux and this free() syntax caught my attention:

```
free((char *) area );
```

What's the difference between this and `free( area );` ?

Answer (score 17):

The signature of `free` is:

```
void free(void *ptr);
```

So if `area` is a pointer type that is returned by `malloc` or its cousins, the conversion in `free((char *) area );` is pointless.

Unless... if the code is really, really old, that is, before **ANSI C** introduced `void *` as generic pointer.  In that ancient time, `char *` is used as generic pointer.

Comment: Indeed, the code is somewhat old, circa 1990, written for old school Unix systems of that era.  area is a pointer in a structure member declared as an int.  Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

If someone were storing a pointer to dynamic allocated data in a non-pointer type sanctioned by the standard, i.e. `area`  is declared as [**`intptr_t`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer) for example, this casts the non-pointer to a pointer type and allows it to be freed.

If `area` is already a pointer type, this makes no sense at all with any C code written in the last quarter-century.

Comment: Yes, it is indeed the case for area.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The signature of `free()` in the standard is wrong. It should have been `void free(const void *);` to be really correct. This has the consequence that you have to upcast a `const *` when you want to free it without a warning.

There is [a Linus Torvald rant about on why `free()` should take a `const *`](http://yarchive.net/comp/const.html).

EDIT: The fundamental idea why the issue is controversial comes from the fact that in general people think that the `const` has any bearing on the memory pointed to by the pointer, i.e. that the pointer points on read-only memory. This is patently false. The `const` qualification is a property of the pointer, not of the thing it points to. This is an important distinction.

Comment: I'm not convinced about that. `malloc` returns non-const, so for one thing you need to have a cast in between the `malloc` and `free` for this to be needed. Second, `const` indicates a contract that means you do not modify the contents of the memory pointed to. `free`ing that memory is a violation of that contract. I can't think think of any arguments for it, so I'd be interested in arguments that are pro-const.

Comment: MicroVirus, read Linus' rant, he explains it better as I ever could and he is right.

Comment: @MicroVirus: Free doesn't modify the contents. It obliterates its very existence.

Comment: This answer is wrong and Linus is wrong. Semantically, if you have stipulated that it's not permitted to modify an allocated object through a pointer `p` to it, then `free(p)` is a violation of that stipulation: ending the lifetime of an object is a (serious!) modification.

Comment: I feel that this answer would be useful if it directly explained that one possible reason that `free((T*) p)` might be necessary is that `p` might be a `const T*` (that you own), but as it currently is, this answer seems like more of a rant.

Comment: @R.. From your comment, it seems like you haven't tried understanding Linus's argument: he argues that it *doesn't* modify the object pointed to. It makes the object inaccessible, which is completely different from modifying it. And it seems like he uses "modify" exactly the same way the C standard does: storing a new value. `free` doesn't store any new value (except on some implementations to an extent permitted by the as-if rule). I'm not saying Linus is right or that he's wrong, but if he is wrong, it's not for as simple a reason as you give.

Comment: @hvd I concur with R.. on this. Linus' argument is implementation based, not pure language based, and his closing sentence is pure hamhtt (high-and-mighty-holier-than-though). It wreaks of "I'm smarter than you, and you're a dolt if you don't see it my way". There is no object after `free` has been invoked. Ergo, there is no *valid* object to compare. His rant is just that, and I don't take rants beyond their face value just because of the source. I know a guy named Sutter who thinks VC++ is the shiznit C++ compiler. Riiight.. Just because you're smart doesn't mean you're right.

Comment: @WhozCraig You're right that the argument isn't automatically valid just because it comes from Linus, but nobody claimed it is. :) One thing that crosses my mind is `{ const int a = 0; }`. That's well-defined, but ends the lifetime of an object defined as `const`. Modifying an object defined as `const` is not allowed, so the only way for that block to be valid is if ending the lifetime of an object doesn't count as a modification.

Comment: @WhozCraig Also, "modified" isn't defined in terms of a comparison between a before and an after, so the fact that you cannot perform a comparison doesn't mean that an object is or isn't modified. Given `int a = 0;`, a subsequent `a = 0` is considered a modification in C.

Comment: Yes objects with `const` qualifier can have their lifetimes end. That's not the matter at hand. Allocated objects are never `const`-qualified themselves, but pointers used to store their address can have pointer-to-`const`-qualified-type type. In terms of whether the language defines the behavior, there is nothing wrong with casting away the `const` to modify the pointed-to object. But from a standpoint of using `const` to convey program semantics to the reader and to get the compiler to diagnose modifications via the pointer as errors unless you cast away the `const`, ...

Comment: ... it's wrong to make any modification to the object (including ending its lifetime) via the `const`-qualified pointer. You should be saving and using a non-`const`-qualified pointer for this purpose, and only converting it to a `const`-qualified pointer when passing it to code that *promises not to modify* the pointed-to object. This is the usage that enables the compiler to diagnose erroneous usage (usage that breaks your interface contracts).

Comment: @R.. Again, you call "ending its lifetime" a "modification", but do not provide anything to support calling it a modification. Are you using the term "modification" in its ordinary English meaning, or in the way the language standard uses the term? If the former, then that's fair enough, that's a valid opinion. Linus seems to disagree, that's also a valid opinion, though perhaps expressed poorly. But if you do intend to use it the way the language standard does, then sorry, the language standard is very specific in what is and what isn't a modification, and ending an object's lifetime isn't.

Comment: @R.. Ultimately, everything will be an opinion because the C language doesn't provide any way to destroy objects through pointers, it leaves that for the library. Our current `free` function is defined as taking `void *`, which seems to imply that `const`-qualified pointers shouldn't be used to modify or deallocate the pointed-to objects. If the `free` function did take a `const void *`, that would seem to imply that `const`-qualified pointers shouldn't be used to modify the pointed-to objects, but could be used to destroy them. Either option would be internally consistent.

Comment: @hvd: Either option is *internally* consistent, but only one option is consistent with the use of `const` to protect against programming mistakes. If you pass a `const T *` to a function, you expect the object to retain its contents across the function call; helping enforce this invariant (via compiler diagnostics) is what makes `const` useful. Allowing the function to end the object's lifetime would break that invariant.

Comment: Something that doesn't exist can not be modified. In the perspective of the caller of free() the memory pointed to by the given pointer doesn't exist anymore. The property of the pointer used is irrelevant to that. The promise made not to change the object by the interface is only restricted to that specific pointer. A function declared `f(const char *p1, char *p2)` called with `f(&obj, &obj)` doesn't provide any protection against change of obj. It only says that `p1` will not be used to make the change, that's all.

Comment: Back in 1997, when this rant dates from, there were (and, I'd argue, remain) many more pressing deficiencies in the C api than whether it's worth donning a bowtie before blowing your brains out.